# How CommandParameter works in MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to implement the CommandParameter in my class CommandProvider, which use for a command (Button, etc.) and inherit from ICommand, but I didn't understand how to implement that. Example:

**XAML**

```
<TreeViewItem Header="Playlist" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSourceTree}">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=NewPlaylist}"
                             CommandParameter="{Binding Path=NamePlaylist}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
<TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:PlaylistDB}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=NamePlaylist}">
        </TextBlock>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
</TreeViewItem>
```

The console says, NamePlaylist doesn't found.

And link a function to the Binding `NewPlaylist`:

```
public ICommand NewPlaylist { get { return new CommandProvider((obj) => DoubleClickTest(obj)); } }
```

**Function**

```
public void DoubleClickTest(object obj)
        {
            var tmp = obj as string;
            Console.WriteLine(tmp);
        }
```

So I need to modify my class CommandProvider to take parameter right? How I can do that?

**CommandProvider**

```
public class CommandProvider : ICommand
{
#region Constructors       

public CommandProvider(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

public CommandProvider(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
{
    _execute = execute;
    _canExecute = canExecute;
}

#endregion

#region ICommand Members

public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    return _canExecute != null ? _canExecute(parameter) : true;
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    if (_execute != null)
        _execute(parameter);
}

public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
{
    CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}

#endregion

private readonly Action<object> _execute = null;
private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute = null;
}
```

**PlaylistDB**

```
public class PlaylistDB
    {
        public string NamePlaylist { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to retrieve the `NamePlaylist` in my function `DoubleClickTest()`, and I want to pass it in `CommandParameter`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use The below Class for accepting `commandparameters` Using `ICommand`,

```
public class DelegateCommand: ICommand
{
    #region Constructors       

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute)
    : this(execute, null) { }

    public DelegateCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #endregion

    #region ICommand Members

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute != null ? _canExecute(parameter) : true;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_execute != null)
            _execute(parameter);
    }

    public void OnCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #endregion

    private readonly Action<object> _execute = null;
    private readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute = null;
}
```

Usage:

```
public ICommand CloseCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new DelegateCommand((obj)=>CloseMethod(obj));
        }
    }
```

`obj` is the `command parameter` passed in the above example.

Comment: Ok, i'll try, but how i can call that. Like `public ICommand NewPlaylist { get { return new CommandProvider(obj => DoubleClickTest(), MyBindingParameter ?); } }` MyBindingParameter can be a string ?

Comment: Your BindingParemeters can be any object. you will receive your parameter as object. Check my edit.

Comment: I'll edit my question, because it's a little bit more difficult.

Comment: Yes, i replace my Class `CommandProvider` by your class. But in your usage where is call the function ? Because obj is the `parameter` and CloseSessionCommand is the `binding`.

Comment: `CloseSelectedSession` is the method having parameter as obj. (obj)=>`CloseSelectedSession(obj)`

Comment: I didn't see the difference, sorry. I'll edit with what i have now.

Comment: My `tmp` is empty every time. I miss something but i didn't see where.

Comment: does your obj has value ? does your NamePlaylist  property have value assigned before your double Click ?

Comment: Well i think he doesn't, but i have a `ObservaleCollection<PlaylistDB>`, with 2 element so 2 NamePlaylist. "I'm a test" and "I'm a test 2".

Comment: You are binding `NamePlaylist` property to your CommandParameter. so you need to assign value to the `NamePlaylist` property to get the value. `CommandParameter="{Binding Path=NamePlaylist}" ` There is no role for  your `ObservaleCollection<PlaylistDB>`

Comment: Ok, but that is the probleme, i want to link the `NamePlaylist` to the CommandParameter to have the NamePlaylist of the element who have been double clicked.

Comment: ok then you need a `selected item` for your treeview. Bind that `selected item` with a `property`. then bind the selected item property for your Command Parameter. I believe `treeview` does not have direct selected item property. so you have to think about creating an `Attached Property` to hold your selected item.

Comment: Well i work in a `TreeViewItem`, who doesn't have `SelectedItem` but have `IsSelected` (bool) or `Selected` (event). So can i bind `IsSelected` and in the `IsSelected` i put the value of another Binding to the current NamePlaylist ? I think it's the same probleme... Thank your time by the way

Comment: you can take a look on `Selected event`. in that event you can assign the value you need to pass thru `CommandParameter`.

Comment: Ok, so i have another question (sorry), who can i bind a event in MVVM ?

Comment: That is what you are doing now with Mouse Double click(event). the same way you can bind it for your Selected event.

Comment: Ok i'll try thank you for time. I'll be back i have any probleme.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97900/discussion-between-raphael-teyssandier-and-abin-mathew).